# Array contents not rendering in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am still fairly new to React. I am trying to map the contents of an array in ReactJS. Currently, I am having no results render. Here is the section of code I am using to map the array contents:

```
return (
        <div>
            {this.state.errors.map( (error, index) => 
                <div key={index} className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    {error}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
       )
```

Here is how I am initializing the state:

```
this.state = {
    workoutId:'',
    daysOfWeek:[],
    name:'',
    trainingPlan:'',
    errors: []
}
```

And here is where I am populating the errors array:

```
if(this.state.daysOfWeek.length < 1) {
    this.state.errors.push('Must select at least 1 day to perform workout');
}
if(this.state.workoutId === '') {
    this.state.errors.push('Please select a workout to edit');
}

console.log(this.state.errors);
```

I am seeing that the array is being populated with those strings on the console.log. My understanding of React is that the component will re-render itself when changes are made. Is that correct? Anyway, can someone explain to me why my array contents will not render? I have tried mapping based on if the length of the errors array is greater than 0, which did not work either.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: You can’t manipulate the state object directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** modify your state object or any of the objects it contains directly; you must instead use `setState`. And when you're setting state based on existing state, you must use the callback version of it; [details](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

So in your case, if you want to **add to** the existing `this.state.errors` array, then:

```
let errors = [];
if(this.state.daysOfWeek.length < 1) {
    errors.push('Must select at least 1 day to perform workout');
}
if(this.state.workoutId === '') {
    errors.push('Please select a workout to edit');
}
if (errors.length) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({errors: [...prevState.errors, ...errors]}));
}
```

If you want to **replace** the `this.state.errors` array, you don't need the callback form:

```
let errors = [];
if(this.state.daysOfWeek.length < 1) {
    errors.push('Must select at least 1 day to perform workout');
}
if(this.state.workoutId === '') {
    errors.push('Please select a workout to edit');
}
if (errors.length) { // Or maybe you don't want this check and want to
                     // set it anyway, to clear existing errors
    this.setState({errors});
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In React, you must never assign to `this.state` directly. Use `this.setState()` instead. The reason is that otherwise React would not know you had changed the state.

The only exception to this rule where you assign directly to `this.state` is in your component's constructor.

Comment: ahh I see. So instead, I should push those to a locally declared array, then assign that array to my errors array using setState

Comment: That's exactly right. `let errors = ...; this.setState({errors:errors})`. You don't need to include all the other state properties again, only what you're changing.